# My Django views and URLs aren't matching up somewhere giving me a blank screen

Tags: django, view, django-urls, django-context

I'm new to Python and Django, I've been through the tutorial that builds a blog, I've been through another tutorial that builds an page based on beers and breweries.

While going through this I started my own project while following along. 1st page lists a few states with links, that goes to the 2nd page that lists out specific cities within those states.

From there I want to link to a 3rd site specific items related to that city. the first two pages work great. however when I click the city name no matter what I've tried I get a blank page.

And I can not for the life of me figure out where I'm going wrong. I don't think I fully understand the flow of variables from the views.py to the urls.py to the html.

Maybe someone can give me a little guidance on where I'm going wrong. Again please be patient as I'm very new to Django and have a simplistic grasp of python.

```
class Meta(models.Model):
    rcabbr              = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    slug                = models.SlugField(unique=False)
    state               = models.ForeignKey('State')
    rc_state            = models.CharField(max_length = 3)
    oerp                = models.CharField(max_length=18)
    subgrp              = models.SlugField()
    sonus_pic           = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    ems                 = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    agc                 = models.CharField(max_length=14)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.rcabbr

class State(models.Model):
    name                = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    slug                = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    state_long          = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    owning_site         = models.CharField(max_length=12)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
        return self.state_long
```

and my views.py

```
def StateAll(request):
    statelist = State.objects.all().order_by("name")
    context = {'states':statelist}
    return render_to_response('statelist.html',context,        

    context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def RcView(request, rclist): 
    rcs = Meta.objects.filter(rc_state = rclist)
    context = {'rc_list': rcs} 
    return render_to_response('rclist.html',context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def RateCenterView(request,rcviews): # = rcviews is passed from the URL conf
    rcv = Meta.objects.filter(rcabbr = rcviews)
    context = {'whatrcv': rcv}
    return render_to_response('rcview.html',context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and my URLS.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
    url(r'^meta/$', 'meta.views.StateAll'),
    (r'^meta/(?P<rclist>.*)/$', 'meta.views.RcView'),
    (r'^meta/(?P<rcviews>.*)/$', 'meta.views.RateCenterView'),
)
```

and the snippets of code from page to page
this lists out the states

```
{% for state in states %}
    <p><a href="/meta/{{ state.name }}/">{{ state.state_long }}</a></p>
{% endfor %}
```

this takes the state and lists the cities, with some extra stuff in there just experimenting

```
 {% for rc in rc_list %}
     <p><a href="/meta/{{ rc.slug }}">{{ rc }}</a></p>
     <p>RateCenter Slug:    {{ rc.slug }}</p>
     <p>RateCenter RC_State: {{ rc.rc_state }}</p>
     <p>RateCenter:         {{ rc }}</p>
 {% endfor %}
```

this is the page thats broke

```
 {% for rca in whatrcv %}
    <p>RateCenter Slug:     {{ rca.slug }}</p>
    <p>RateCenter RC_State: {{ rca.rc_state }}</p>
    <p>RateCenter:          {{ rca }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your urls, your two urls are same and also in your html url(href="/meta/city/{{ rc.slug }}) not ending with /. change your url like this one:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
    url(r'^meta/$', 'meta.views.StateAll'),
    (r'^meta/(?P<rclist>.*)/$', 'meta.views.RcView'),
    (r'^meta/city/(?P<rcviews>.*)/$', 'meta.views.RateCenterView'),
)
```

Then change your html like this :

```
 {% for rc in rc_list %}
     <p><a href="/meta/city/{{ rc.slug }}/">{{ rc }}</a></p>
     <p>RateCenter Slug:    {{ rc.slug }}</p>
     <p>RateCenter RC_State: {{ rc.rc_state }}</p>
     <p>RateCenter:         {{ rc }}</p>
 {% endfor %}
```

This will work for you.

Comment: didnt exactly solve my problem however it led me to the answer. so what I did was, changed the urls and the html link as you suggested but that still produced a blank. so went back a step and added "/state/" to my RcView line in the url and the link in the html. then added a simple "/" to the end of my link in the RcView html and its working perfectly. thank you Yogesh for steering me in the right direction.